# Badge proposal: Deduplicator -- nominated to close as duplicate with link (x 30)?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, badges

I would like to propose a badge for the heroic work of hunting down a good duplicate, and nominating to close another question as a duplicate of that.

I'm not entirely sure what the criteria for Deduplicator should be.  I want to reward the mundane but important work of finding a good duplicate to link to, and making the nomination with a suitable link.

Probably, the badge should be awarded when a sufficient number of users have agreed with the duplicate vote.  I see enough scatter in the close votes to want to propose less than a full consensus of five "close as duplicate" votes -- 4 should suffice, maybe even 3 if the others are not competing for another duplicate (i.e. voting to close for other reasons, perhaps constrained to just a few of the possible close reasons).

Also, not sure what the numbers should be.  Maybe doing this 30 times to earn this badge in Bronze, 150 for Silver, 600 for Gold?

What I currently see is a group of high-rep users (I have my eyes on a particular one) who post simple, correct answers to simple, uninspiring questions from the hip, when (IMNSHO) the correct action would be to close as duplicate.

(There is a grey area here. Some simple FAQ-style questions are so specific that no duplicate completely and accurately addresses that specific combination of requirements.  Those should probably be left alone, perhaps with a downvote as "unlikely to help future visitors".)

I can understand how answering these questions is the path of least resistance -- posting an accepted answer gains you rep, and search sucks; so it's easier and more rewarding to simply write a three-line answer, and probably have it accepted in short order.  Offering a badge for what I perceive as the correct action would at least dress it up as a condoned alternative to answering.

(Ideally, I would like for the duplicate linker to actually gain more rep than you get for an accepted answer, but I realize this is probably pie in the sky.)

To clarify the proposed name, I think of this as locating duplicates and refactoring to reduce duplication.  Hence, we perform [data deduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication) (at least, hopefully, in terms of future answers) by doing this.  I'm certainly open to better naming proposals.

Comment: deduplicator makes it sound like you are finding a post closed as a duplicate , and reopening it, since it's not a dup

Comment: Does having a gold badge count as having enough agreement?

Comment: @Ben: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  I updated the wording slightly regarding the Bronze vs. Silver vs. Gold thresholds but I guess that's not what you were asking about.

Comment: @lostsock: Ack; see update.  Alternative naming suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: I agree this could be a positive incentive. Regarding the terminology, I would suggest *Switchman* or similar, i.e. emphasizing "putting in the right direction" rather than "removing duplication".

Comment: Gold badge holders can close on their own, but you're suggesting that someone else must agree.

Comment: I completely agree with this proposal. I think many users would probably avoid answering these type of questions if it has a duplicate close   vote already.

Comment: @Ben: Good question, sorry for not immediately catching your drift. I'm a bit divided on that particular point.  I'm thinking maybe the consensus factor *is* important here.  You can still find duplicates in topics where you don't have the gold star (-:

Comment: There is a long history of related requests e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions

Comment: [That name is already taken](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator)

Comment: @tripleee The whole point of the dupe-hammer is that gold-badge holders are *better* at finding duplicates in their gold badge tags. I'm not sure what the right answer is, but it seems harsh to say: "This thing that you are an expert in; you can't get progress for utilizing your expertise". For example, Jon Skeet would have a hard time getting this badge (the one badge he wouldn't have!).

Comment: How about calling the proposed badge _Thesauric_, as in a user that resolves questions with others that are synonyms or related concepts?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Like I said, if Jon Skeet wants the badge, he is welcome to visit the [tag:bash] tag, where we don't see him much, and which is ripe for some heavy deduplication. But anyway, like I also said, I'm not heavily partial either way on this particular implementation detail. I'm fine with Golden Hammer users getting this badge for their hammering work, too; if I have an objection, it's mainly that it seems to complicate the rules for being awarded the badge.

Comment: (I'm also not entirely convinced that gold-badge holders are somehow automatically better at finding duplicates. You can get gold without ever marking anything as duplicate, and as a matter of fact, some golden badgers probably did.)

Comment: @IanRingrose Thanks for the link.  I was surprised to not find any existing proposal I could upvote but I foolishly did not search on MSE.

Comment: **Don't name badges after users:** [Deduplicator](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator)

Comment: I can see how this is problematic, and yours is already the second comment to bring it up; but seriously, do we have anything in place to prevent a user from registering an account with an existing badge name?  If not, why is this a bigger problem?

Comment: ... To be sure, I was able to sign up a sock puppet account with the user name [Altruist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4120000/altruist)

Comment: Calls for a "Duperman!" badge (complete with cape)

Comment: A good alternative name might be something along the lines of "signpost-maker"

Comment: I take it the key point is to reduce the incidence of repwhoring by  going after the low hanging fruit? Why not instead go for treating 'duplicate of...' type posts as answers that gain reputation? I mean, part of the point of the rep system is to 'note' who's participating in the community in a meaningful way, and dupe coalescing counts.

Comment: I think the "Deduplicator" name does make sense - you're finding duplicate questions and neutralising them.

Comment: @Sobrique: Thanks, that's what the "pie in the sky" comment in the question refers to.  If there is a broad consensus to grant rep for marking duplicates, we should go for that instead.  Should I post that as a separate feature request?  (Or does it already exist?)

Comment: @BenVoigt I like Duperman!

Comment: no lame pun about @deduplicator?

Answer (score 15):

There are three issues with this proposal.

### 1.  We establish no criteria for "good duplicate".

No, I won't accept upvotes alone as a blanket condition, since older questions that have been upvoted like crazy may either be out of date, or even blatantly wrong.  It's tough to say that there's any one good duplicate, but the most conventional thing to do would be to weigh upvotes and the number of inbound links from other questions which are closed as a duplicate of it would be a fair measure - it weighs both the popular vote with the consensus of those denizens in the tag itself.

I'd expect the number of inbound links to weigh a bit heavier than votes - maybe 5 to 1?

### 2.  Duplicates by themselves aren't necessarily a bad thing.

The idea is to have as few duplicates as possible, but if a question which *seems* like a duplicate is answered in a completely novel way to the duplicate, then we have gained new knowledge, and that shouldn't be punished.

Admittedly, there are several different questions and answers to what integer division is, and why it works in such a way in the Java tag alone.  But, for the most part, the ones that have added something novel to the table (i.e. behavior when dividing a negative integer) shouldn't be closed as duplicates, necessarily.

### 3.  The name.

Call it something like:

- Archivist
- Librarian
- Curator
- Chronicle

Comment: For 2. Is the 'duplicate' is better than the original, close the original.

Comment: Duplicates are okay, but they should be marked as duplicates, so that newcomers find the (more or less) canonical answers and vote up/down on their answers, instead of post new (possibly buggy) near-duplicates of the existing answers.  I certainly agree that there are near-duplicates which should not be closed as duplicates, but that is beside the point here IMHO.

Comment: My criteria for a "good duplicate" is that enough users agreed with the nomination to close.  If it's good enough to actually close as duplicate, it's good enough to count towards the badge as well.  Problems with the current model are, to my mind, beside the point here.

Comment: Out of the proposed names, I like "Curator" the best, but all of them are kind of ... vague.  (That seems to be in line with the general naming convention for badges, so maybe it's okay.)

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Well... The world is not strictly black and white (i.e. not binary).  It quite possible to have multiple equally good answers that (let say) differ in approach, syntax, technology, use of 3rd-party tools, etc. You cannot always expect one (correct) answer to cover all the bases.

Comment: "Duplicates" are a difficult topic: for example, I'm quite sure to already have seen a duplicate having better answers than the original -- but closed nevertheless. Was it right or wrong?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Again, that discussion is important, but out of scope for this question IMHO.

Comment: It's better if the novel answer appears in the same place as all the others, not in a new question. That's the whole point of de-duplicating.

Comment: @tripleee `My criteria for a "good duplicate" is that enough users agreed with the nomination to close.` - What about users who have a gold tag badge and can VTC as duplicate without anyone agreeing?

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, edit the original to be better than the duplicate.

Comment: @izkata As discussed above, I regard that as a trivial detail. I originally thought they should be excluded, but I'm fine either way. The current situation is certainly that those duplicates are good enough, and I'm not about to propose any change to that (nor is this the right place to discuss such changes).

Comment: @tripleee Whoops, missed that.  The phrasing of your comment on this answer just made it stick out in my mind and I didn't see it in these comments

Comment: I agree with you, but something MUST be done. For example, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions (this is just one question I just saw a minute ago on SO) I could open the same basic question asked on three different pages using the links provided in the comments. Okay, so let's say that the answers differ, wouldn't it still be better to collect them under one question? If there is a question which cannot be simply answered with one answer, why should the same question with different answers be spread across SO?

Comment: Also, there's a reason additional answers are allowed after the OP has accepted one.  It's OK for there to be multiple *different* correct answers on a single question.

Comment: Naming suggestion: "One post to rule them all".