# Where is the Linked tab?

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions

Is it just me or the Linked tab is no longer visible in any questions? I can still see it on meta but not on the main site.

I am using it a lot to find the needed questions.

Below an example:

> [image]

At least 3 questions should appear as linked but nothing.

<sup><sup>a random [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394053/8620333) to trigger the linked here</sup></sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be resolved.

TL;DR; The cause was a very unhappy SQL Server due to a bad execution plan for the query to get linked questions.

I noticed an alert this morning for one of our primary SQL Servers, investigated the issue, and found a terrible plan. After updating the statistics on a table, we stopped throwing exceptions and the query started returning in a proper time. If you look really close, you might be able to see when the issue started:

> [image]

Things have settled down, and the server is happy again.

Comment: I don't know... I think a hand-drawn circle could always help... ;-)

Comment: All I see is an under utilized SQL Server until 5 AM  ... I see myself out ...

Comment: Might be happening again https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394171

Comment: It is still not resolved for some questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming?rq=1. Does SO cache the panel even if it’s not populated due to an exception? Can empty sections due to exceptions be excluded from the cache?