# Why “Linked” panel disappeared on Stack Overflow site?

Tags: support, bug, linked-questions

Since yesterday I’ve noticed that  “Linked” panel on the right side of questions disappeared on Stack Overflow site. I’ve looked at highly popular questions, that have references to other SO questions, e.g. [What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming?rq=1), but “Linked” panel is missing.
The same behaviour is on Chrome on Windows 10 and on Safari on IPad.

Other sites continue to have the panel, e.g. SO Meta and SE Meta.
 Is it a bug or A/B testing of a new functionality? If the last, please do not remove the panel.

UPDATE: the question is a report of a current bug and shouldn’t be closed as a duplicate of the old bug, that is marked as “completed”. The current problem is not fixed yet.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394157/where-is-the-linked-tab might be occurring again