# “You can edit the question or post a new one”

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, post-notice

What you read in the title is the advice that is given in the post notice when a question gets closed as off-topic. You might be aware that these [post notices got an overhaul 6 to 8 weeks ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide).

This an example of a notice an OP sees:

> [image: Post notice for off-topic question]
>
> <sub>(Image taken from [Should I edit a closed question or post a new one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394530))</sub>

It reads:

> Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can [edit the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/394552/edit) or [post a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Similarly, the advice for questions closed as duplicates reads:

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

The wording of these post notices was changed with this goal in mind, according to [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/339731#comment1135535_339731):

> The thing is, we previously had language up there recommending that users edit to reopen. And what it led to is...almost no edit, and from those edit, almost no reopens. So we are (intentionally) removing the dangling carrot of the reopen from the language here. Not because adding it is a good temporary band-aid fix. But because we don't think that it accomplished anything positive (and can even be negative). We are aiming for UX changes that will hopefully improve close/reopen. Adding this language back here is not part of our intended solution.

I don’t want (and please don’t feel invited) to discuss whether this change was communicated effectively to the users that are empowered to cause this notice to appear on a question.

I only want to fix one link in that post notice. And that is the “post a new one” link. Currently that links brings you to [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Yes, you’re given the no barrier entry to re-ask your exact same question. No questions asked. Leading to trainwrecks I linked to earlier and I’m sure you have seen more on main.

I propose the minimal change that can make this a tiny bit better: please link the text “post a new one” to the help center article [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

The link text stays the same, no-one will even notice something changed, but an OP that chooses that option is presented with guidance instead of an invite to make the same mistake again.

I realize it is tempting to rewrite all that text but my proposal leaves as little room possible for discussion, mishaps, and interpretation so it can be done in 6 to 8 hours, instead of 6 to 8 weeks. Can you please make this change so our curators don’t have to argue with disgruntled users that, rightfully so, claim they followed advice given in the post notice?

Comment: like the 6-8 hours, +1 :)

Comment: IMO "Post a new one should not be an option". That change was not a good one. And it probably takes people faster to a question ban. Besides that, if the link and "post a new one" has to stay I fully agree with your proposal.

Comment: Recent [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60617976), [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60598808), [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60576667) that this wording is working counterproductively.

Comment: There are a couple related posts that I’m linking here to find them more easily:
[Why doesn’t the system prevent repeating the _exact_ same question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396474/4642212),
[Why is there no mention of _editing_ the post as a suggested option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339734/289905),
[How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332500/289905),
[New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015/289905).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is done. Post notice text on closed notices that is shown to the post owner, advising them to post a new question is now linked to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Does this work on MSE? I still see _“Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, [ask a new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).”_, linking directly to the `/ask` page on my post. Looks like a couple of changes have regressed, including [Migration message for per-site metas make no sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343455/289905).

Comment: I just realized that this may not be a regression. You probably only changed the link of “post a new one” in _off-topic_ post notices. The link for “ask a new one” in _duplicate_ post notices _still_ links to `/ask`, but it’s _exactly the same problem_ there.

Comment: Here is an example where a duplicate went belly up: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398100/578411

Comment: This is still [not fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402432/4642212) for duplicates.

Comment: "Ask a new one" should become "Ask a different one"

Comment: There is still a problem with how the information is conveyed to the user.  I recently received a notice saying exactly: "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one. Closed 55 mins ago."  So as the the question did not resolve my question, I did exactly as I was instructed, I "asked a new one", restating my question to highlight the specific information I was looking for.  I was then told it was inappropriate and wrong to do so.

Comment: Furthermore, I was told my new post was now complicating matters because it was viewed as a duplicate of my previous post.  It felt like a bit of a kerfuffle but fortunately things finally got ironed out and my original post was reinstated, and I deleted the second one.  Nevertheless, for users who haven't gone through this experience, as long as the message continues as it is, you may fully expect these kinds of incidents to continue.