# Why does this user keep removing my attempt to re-ask a question?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I have asked a question on Stack Overflow but this user keeps closing it, saying that it is a duplicate of another [closed] question

My questions:
[How can I force an old-style Alt-Tab dialog programatically in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247560/how-can-i-force-an-old-style-alt-tab-menu-programatically-in-windows-10)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266734/how-can-i-force-an-old-style-alt-tab-menu-programatically-in-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266990/how-can-i-force-an-old-style-alt-tab-menu-programatically-in-c

The initial reason was that the post was off-topic, but I re-worded my question such that it is definitely ON topic for Stack Overflow. However, that user removed my posts nonetheless.

What am I supposed to do in this situation?

Comment: Don't repost questions, the later are dupes of the earliest. The earliest is too vague. There's a way to anything. SO is not here to write code or teach programming. You need to ask a question with smaller scope. Regardless, you must wait for your improved post to be voted open. Don't repost. PS Is there a way? Yes. Did that help? Was that the question you meant to ask? How does somebody justify that answer? It's a tutorial and/or writing your code.

Comment: I apologise but at the top it was saying "repost" question. So I thought that would be the best course of action after having a post deleted.

Comment: Another case of ["Post a new one"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/you-can-edit-the-question-or-post-a-new-one) ...

Comment: @rene exacly, that is partly my reasoning behind re-posting the question. My other justification would be that I believed my post to have been closed unfairly. Another reason would be the fact that my edited post would not be re-opened instantaneously

Comment: When you clicked that link in the post notice you were brought to the /ask page, right? Not the guidance in the helpcentre? And for your other point: No one here acts "unfairly" we might take an action based on incomplete information but that is hardly unfair, we don't have a magic 8 ball. If an edit would lead to immediate re-opening we could as well do away with closure. I know all people on reddit, Quora and Twitter would love that, but we care for quality so we rather have 3 pair of eyes doing a sanity check on the post and each other before allowing answers on an edited question.

Comment: @rene I disagree, I believe it's unfair, specifically the part where I feel like I have to persuade people that my question is related to programming when I belive it's quite obvious that it is, give random people a hammer, and everything is a nail. They are too eager to dismiss questions as off-topic, just because my post does not contain code.

Comment: That you personally feel something is unfair is *never* a justification to subvert the site's rules. I'm something of a subject-matter expert when it comes to Windows programming, and I find myself in complete agreement with David that your *original draft* of the question did not make clear that it was a programming question. We do get a lot of people who are asking off-topic questions just because of how popular Stack Overflow is, and we don't try to judge motives. Posts are handled based on how they appear at the time. Fortunately, there are mechanisms to clarify and/or correct mistakes.

Comment: I disagree I'm random people. I'm a blurry flower that was trusted with the hammer by fellow members of this community.

Answer (score 19):

Nobody *"removed"* any of your posts.

However, your questions were closed as a duplicate, because they are fundamentally the same question. I don't think anyone will disagree for a moment that:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266734/how-can-i-force-an-old-style-alt-tab-menu-programatically-in-c
  and
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266990/how-can-i-force-an-old-style-alt-tab-menu-programatically-in-c

are *identical* to your original question:

[How can I force an old-style Alt-Tab dialog programatically in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247560/how-can-i-force-an-old-style-alt-tab-dialog-programatically-in-windows-10)

Now, your original question was also closed by David (and two others users) as off-topic because, in its original form, it didn't look like a programming question. Indeed, it looked like a technical support question about using Windows itself, which are better asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). In fact, Norbert gave you a link to what seemed to be [a duplicate question already asked and answered on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/114001/getting-back-the-old-alt-tab-windows-switching-behavior-in-windows-7).

However, your more recent edits have made clear that you are actually asking a programming question. As such, I've re-opened the original question.

For future reference, this is the way it *should* work. If a question gets closed as unclear or off-topic, then it should be edited (if possible) to comply with [our requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If and when that happens, then the original question can be re-opened, either by the same people who originally closed it or different people with equivalent privileges. Under no circumstances should you re-post the same question multiple times.

Comment: you forgot this one in your list - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274651/how-can-i-use-the-windows-api-c-or-c-to-force-the-old-alt-tab-style-switche... :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did. But don't worry, I found it while I was going through and deleting the questions. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, but I don't believe moderators will "go-back" and re-open my question given that I have edited it.

Comment: @Cherona It happens all the time. It's how the system is designed to work. Regardless, it is *breaking the rules* to continue reposting the same question, so don't do that again.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think it's a very sound system, a moderator should not need to go back and re-open the question, I don't believe they care or have the time to do so. That's why I just opened a new question - because it's open by default and does not require moderator approval. Why should closed posts require moderator approval to be re-opened, but new questions don't require moderator approval at all?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a moderator. Anyone with privileges to vote to close a question also has privileges to vote to re-open it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions. Note that there is [an entire review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) designed for the express purpose of reviewing recently-closed questions that may deserve to be reopened. The intention of the "close" functionality is to allow problematic questions to be put temporarily on hold until such time as they can be fixed, and then reopened. @Cherona

Comment: A moderator only got involved here because (A) you posted on Meta where I happened to see it, and (B) you created a bunch of duplicate questions which required moderator clean-up (i.e., *actual* deletion, not closure).

Comment: I "poked" Yaakov: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/you-can-edit-the-question-or-post-a-new-one#comment772123_394578

Comment: @Cherona well I mean it was a system sound enough to make Stack *the* Q&A website. Was so sound it got popularity enough that now random ppl on the internet **absolutely** want their answer from here. And ppl forget that we became popular because of that moderation and quality control.... Removing it is bound to be.... Unpopular, and also very likely to break some things about what stack is and how it achieve its goals