# How can I post a question on Stack Overflow without getting it closed down by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, meta

I posted a question earlier today which was closed by a moderator because it was not focused enough and needed more information. Fair enough.

I was invited to edit the question, which I duly did, but some two hours later the question remains closed.

I read the advisory again, and see that is says " You can edit the question or post a new one". So I do what I'm told and post and new one. Slightly different title because I noticed a typo in the original question.

Even faster this time, the second question is closed for being a duplicate.

What is needed to get some help and friendly advice around here?

From the comments it appears that people are willing to help, but some higher power is bent on preventing this. Why?

---

First post: *[How do I make this date string less verbose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397859/how-to-make-a-plain-test-string-less-verbose)*

Second post: *[How to make a plain text string less verbose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399874/how-to-make-a-plain-text-string-less-verbose)*

Comment: **1.** There was no mod involved in this. **2.** Ask a good question, which doesn't warrant a close of question. **Summary:** I believe this question, again, is not a right question for Stack Overflow. So your question will be closed by the community members.

Comment: With respect Praveen, I am not a react JS specialist a or a blockchain enthusiast or a full stack developer, but rather someone who does not have a brain the size of a small planet, with a question I have and hoping to receive some kind hearted help and advice. Please reconsider your action and allow the community to participate.

Comment: @MrPaulDriver Sorry, I wasn't being rude anytime. Hope I am not. All I am saying is, with due respect, this is not the right place to add this post, [meta] is. Secondly, there is a good guidance on asking the best question. See [ask]. Hope that was helpful. And I am also happy to help you out with other questions too.

Comment: Looking at your question, it looks like it's too broad and doesn't have enough focus. You should dive into the code generating those strings and post some details about that rather than asking a yes or no type question like you have.

Comment: @MrPaulDriver I guess you're again mistaken. I haven't done any negative action directly to you. I am trying to help you to write the best question possible. If you do this way, if not me (which I never was), others might find it too broad and close it. I am trying to help you to get the answer that you need.

Comment: @MrPaulDriver It's been migrated to meta and it's open! All the best.

Comment: First post is... too unclear. we don't know where you're getting the string from, how it's generated, how you're attaching it to the page, what your javascript environment looks like, anything. In what way is the second different?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not somewhere where you can just post a question without code and expect people to answer or give advice without seeing how things are being done currently. Both posts were pretty much the same, entirely lacking any kind of code that might help us give an appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: Put another way, if you read your question from your phone and have nothing but your phone to answer it, what information would you need to add to the question such that you'd have any idea what is happening there?

Comment: Just FYI, actual moderators have little diamonds next to their name. Like me. These actions were taken by people with [earned privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Related: [“You can edit the question or post a new one”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394552/4642212).

Answer (score 20):

I'll try to answer your questions in order.

> I was invited to edit the question, which I duly did, but some two hours later the question remains closed.

As it should. Your question is still very broad and isn't asking a specific question: "I am asking if Javascript could be used to make this less verbose."

This is a simple yes/no question. You need to show the code that is generating these strings so we have some more details about what's going on behind the curtains and provide a better answer. As it stands, we simply don't have enough information to give you a good answer. You need to ask a better question that isn't a yes/no answer and isn't just a request for code.

Next, regarding your second question. If you're posting a new question it needs to be new. Fixing typos does not make it a new question. It was properly closed as a duplicate of your first post. "You can edit the question or post a new one" may be slightly misleading but the policy on posting duplicates is fairly clear.

> From the comments it appears that people are willing to help, but some higher power is bent on preventing this

This is really not the case. Your questions were *voted* to be closed by the community. No higher powers were involved here, nobody is out to get you. The questions you asked just don't meet the requirements.

Please spend some time to do some more digging in order to improve your original question and it should be reopened. You've been given an extraordinary amount of advice on what you need to do in order to improve your question. I highly recommend you refocus your efforts on that.

Comment: related: [Question closed because yes/no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)

Comment: My question starts with "I am complete novice with Javascript and would appreciate some help". Based on this totally accurate and focused information, how do you arrive at a point where you can reasonably suggest that should "spend some time to do some more digging in order to improve your original question". Hey hum, I'll try again shall I?

Comment: Funny. My reputation score just went up by 10 points for getting absolutely nowhere.

Comment: I'm not really sure what point you're trying to make. Strictly speaking, "I am complete novice with Javascript and would appreciate some help" shouldn't even be included in your question because it's irrelevant and unnecessary info. That being said, it had nothing to do with my recommendation. Could you clarify what you're trying to say?

Comment: @MrPaulDriver I assume you mean: 'Im saying I'm a newbie, ppl should be nicer'. But that's not how stack works. It's how ppl **assume** stack works, so they post stuff like this. Then it doesn't change and they get angry. You need to realize Stack isn't there to answer questions and teach people. It's a side effect of the *very* clear goal: build a high quality repository of programming content. With low noise, and with a lot of searchability for the future. 'help I'm new I dunno how to do X' is a question for a mentor/tutor. Not a q&a site like stack. It's not BAD. It just is.

Comment: @Patrice. Thank you for taking the time to review my post and contribute a reply. But I disagree with you. My opening posts does not mean "people should be nicer" it means exactly what I stated; this being "I don't know much about Javascript and I'm looking for some help". 

Your statement that "Stack isn't there to answer questions and teach people" is also misplaced. I refer you to the the button which is labeled "Ask question" as well as the home page of stackoverflow where it says "Get answers to more than 16.5 million questions and give back by sharing your knowledge with others".

Comment: Via comments, a number of people have provided real help in terms or pointing me in the right direction, rather than (arrogantly) saying "ask the right question". Indeed one member went as far as providing a very good answer via a comment in an unrelated question which I posted some months ago.

Answer (score 14):

> How to post a question on stack overflow without getting it closed down?

We have an awesome [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and a [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). If you follow that along one of the, at first sight unimportant, bullets is crucial here:

> If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?

It is possible to have a question without code, but if you present us requirements and nothing more then we assume you're asking us to do all the work from scratch. You need luck to not have such a question closed.

In your question you say:

> I suspect this problem is more than a simple character replacement thing.

So you know about character replacement? Why didn't you give that a try so you don't have to *suspect* things, you could have actually proven that it was more complex. Users here are then more than happy to expand on what you already know.

If I needed the reputation badly I could have whipped something up like this:

```js
function lessVerbose(value) {
  var comma = value.indexOf(','); // find the comma
  var first = value.substring(0, comma); // text till the comma
  var last = value.substring(comma); // comma and the rest
  var remains = last.replace(first,''); // remove same text 
  
  return first + remains;
}

console.log(lessVerbose('August 10th, 08:00AM - August 10th 08:15AM'));
```

but then I read the rest of your question. Obviously this is not about JavaScript. It is about PHP, right? Or where else does that PHP dateformat link come from?

Wait, it is a Drupal CMS. So this is part of some Drupal plugin? Where would my lame code go then? In a JavaScript file you have control over? Where are you going to call that function then? How will it change the right things?

I wonder if your question is not too broad.

And that I raise those doubts is maybe my bad. I'm only here for the reputation. But any future visitor will probably have the same confusion and looking at my lame answer they still have no idea how that actually answers the question (and theirs).

Remember these bits at the right hand side of your screen from when you drafted your question:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I feel your question skipped over some of the bullets in that guidance where it could have used (some) expansion / clarification. But if none of that is useful, then we need a Meta post about how we can get better guidance in front of the eyes of askers before their question gets curated.

Comment: this might be the case and I accept that perhaps I did not provide enough information with my original question. However, I did make a point of editing my question and went on to provide a good amount of additional information. 

I admit that I was somewhat annoyed that some two hours later my question was still closed and I apologize it some of later comments were deemed by some to be "obtuse".

But, I do not apologize for making this meta post to complain about how my question has been dealt with. Please be in no doubt about this.

Comment: The fact is, my question was closed by a community member, but after providing more information, no feedback was provided to suggest that my question was still "not a right question for Stack Overflow".

I have "earned" a fairly good reputation on another stackexchange site where the culture is much more disposed helping people. 

It seems that here, voicing an opinion is likely to result in losing reputation. This seems wrong and quite sad.

Comment: Also a bit silly that this post remains closed rather than providing a channel for honest feedback.

Comment: It's also marked as a duplicate which is not the case.

Comment: I've just re-read your post and to clarify, this is about javascript rather than php. As mentioned earlier, the developer has not not yet had time to fix up the php, so my question is about modifying the current output. Thank you for your time and suggestions, it is appreciated.