# "How do I ask a good question" page needs explicit statement "Don't repost your questions"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, help-center, question-quality

At the moment, part of the closed question notice ***You can edit the question or post a new one*** links to the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* page as requested in *[“You can edit the question or post a new one”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/you-can-edit-the-question-or-post-a-new-one)*.

That part is fine. However, the "How do I ask a good question?" page never explicitly states that reposting the same (or very similar) question is not the right course of action and that such a new question will most likely be closed as a duplicate.

Another solution would be removing the part ***or post new one*** from the closed question notices.

---

Here are some examples of misunderstanding instructions on the closed post notice:

*[Why doesn't the system prevent repeating the "exact" same question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396474/why-doesnt-the-system-prevent-repeating-the-exact-same-question)*

*[How can I post a question on Stack Overflow without getting it closed down by a moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400270/how-to-post-a-question-on-stack-overflow-without-getting-it-closed-down-by-a-mod)*

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396474/8620333 .. I am getting this everyday. I close a question, the OP repeat it again and always claim I am wrong because the system told him to do so

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394887/8967612 - The problem isn't with the "How to Ask" page (although it would be nice to add the statement there too). The main problem is with post notices because many users won't really read that page anyway. The wording of the post notice needs to change. E.g., "**Do Not repost the same question**. You can edit this question or if you have a **different** question, you can post a new one."

Comment: @41686d6564 I agree that real culprit are post notices, but suggestions to change post notices were not accepted. I would be more than happy to see that original issue resolved. That does not mean that "How to ask" page could not be additionally improved, too.

Comment: [nominated this to be featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400289/839601)

Comment: This isn't just confined to closed questions - I have seen questions reposted because they haven't been answered (or the answers / feedback are not to the asker's satisfaction) after an hour or two.

Comment: @snakecharmerb True, but things got much worse since close notices changed.

Comment: I always clarify that the notice says "post a new question", not "repost the same question".

Answer (score 56):

I agree with this, and I think the best place to address it is the closed-question notice (though it might be good to note it on the How to Ask page).  In many cases, questions are closed due to advice a user could have found somewhere in the help center, so the notice should present the most relevant information directly rather than behind a link.  In particular, it should indicate a few things that are frequently missed:

- Don't repost the same question; instead, edit this question to fix the issues.
- Once the question is edited, it will be reviewed by the community to determine if it will be reopened.
- If you have a different question, you can ask a new question (i.e., don't edit the question into a completely different question).

I'd propose the following wording:

> You can [edit this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400273) to fix these problems. If you have a different question, you can [post a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you edit the text of this question, it will be [reviewed by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) to decide if it should be reopened.

There may be a better link that describes the reopen review (suggestions welcome).  The "edit this question" link would drop the user into the editor for the question (right now it just links to this page because I couldn't figure out a better way to add a fake link).

Comment: Also, add that making trivial edits to push it into the review queue is a waste of time, and should be avoided. Add the text "Please don't make trivial edits, try to make the question free from these problems".

Comment: @10Rep I think that would be a good addition to a help center page somewhere, but it's probably not significant enough to put in the few sentences of a post notice.  I think part of the problem with people making trivial edits right now is that they don't know that it pushes it into the review queue (which for edits from people other than the asker, [it really shouldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398340/208273)).  If they wanted a longer post notice, I'd recommend a bulleted list similar to the one in my answer here that gives slightly more detail.

Comment: A problem I have with "reviewed by the community" is that the first, and only the first, edit after closure puts it in the queue. This means that if the OP, let alone someone else, edits cosmetics (e.g. grammar) it goes into the queue, remains closed, and no amount of editing will put it back in the queue. This is a different problem that the wording here, but important nonetheless. I wrote a more extensive argumentation [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395911/5211833).

Comment: @Adriaan I believe we are in agreement here: my [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398340/208273) that I linked in my previous comment makes a very similar argument.

Answer (score 26):

I agree.

It's crazy how the part "*or post a new one*" in

> You can edit the question or post a new one

implicitly implies that someone can or even should repost the same horrific content of the orginial question as new question again without even changing anything because of the OR'ed "edit the question".

We definitely need some change in here.

The suggestion to posting a new question is IMHO also wrong. A question rather should be edited than to abandoned and posting a new fixed one instead.

I wonder why they even implemented such wording once? Maybe because of a susceptible reopening principle? If yes, then we also need to discuss about that.

Also a problem I see very very often is that many new user don't understand how closing and most of all reopening works and that reopening is even possible.

That's also the reason why some users with closed questions, doesn't feel to improve their questions after they have been closed because they think it would have no reason anymore.

We need to teach them more about that if they fixed their question appropriately, the question is likely to get reopened.

My suggestion:

> "You can [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that your question can [get reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). Posting the same content in a new question without any significant change will get the post closed again."

We could save many time and effort for anyone at the [refuse collection](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) with this change.

Comment: But "the same horrific question" is obviously not "a new one". If it's new it's not the same question. The wording might be a bit ambiguous, but there's a difference between a new post, and a new question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo "*But "the same horrific question" is obviously not "a new one". If it's new it's not the same question.*" - I've seen cases where an OP literally just dumped the same question again. Often shadowed by pretending to be a "different" user.  So the question is literally the same, just new posted.

Comment: I know, I've seen that many times too. The wording is too ambiguous for many people to understand the meaning of the sentence as intended. I'm just stating what the intention of the sentence was, your "[...] implicitly implies that someone can or even should repost the same horrific question again" is not correct. People interpret it as meaning that, but it doesn't.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Better now?