# How should we handle suspicious questions with close-explanations in question-text?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, banner

While reviewing triage today, I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146863/how-to-return-json-data-check-match-with-foreach-return-to-id). In the question, you'll find text that is shown when a question gets closed for not being focused enough. But it is not shown in the usual blue information box, but as the text of the question itself. The text has been there since the initial question.

[image]

To me, this looks like a bad bot that included this text in its generated question, as it appears often. Is there another possible explanation for this? What would be your course of action?

Comment: A more plausible explanation is that the user simply copied their closed (and deleted?) question and posted it again.

Comment: _What would be your course of action?_ Nothing. Its already closed. If they repost without addressing the close reason, they will be digging themselves into a hole.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: Good point, probably I was reading too much into that, while there is a more plausible explanation.

Comment: Another explanation is that they have been question banned and created a new account to repost the question (which is against the rules, as it would be avoiding a restriction placed on another of their account), which might make it harder to find the original content.

Comment: A re-post by just copying the UI including the banner seems [most plausible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73120730/15497888). The account associated with the re-post has been removed and community just roomba'd it so I'd say this post been handled.

Comment: Could someone post a screenshot so that <10k users can see the question?

Comment: Considering the user's deletion, seems it was a *new* account. If it was simply a repost, I suspect the mod action would have been more likely that the repost deleted and the old question undeleted (and left closed).

Comment: @DonaldDuck: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzQ52.png

Comment: The original post that the text is in part copied from is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73120730), for reference.  They did, at least, make _some_ edits to convert the image to text.

Comment: @Tomerikoo not sure that's a good dupe here. The assumption there seems to be that the dupe question is still around. Here even the user is nuked, so there's no (non-diamond) way to see any duplicate questions. At least the premise here doesn't consider "I found the original copy".

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I would say that the copy-pasted close banner is a good indication that the question is a duplicate, no diamond needed to figure that out. And the dupe still holds. From the accepted: *"Just close the new one as a duplicate of the old one.

__If that's not possible, close the new question with the same reason the old one was closed__."*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Why does this happen?

As mentioned in the comments to the question, most instances of this are likely due to a user reposting a question that was closed. This is not necessarily done with bad intent, but instead is due to a misunderstanding of how the close-reopen process works on the site. This misunderstanding stems in part from the misleading guidance in the close banner which says "*You can edit the question or post a new one*". There's an existing discussion about this issue and how to deal with it: ["How do I ask a good question" page needs explicit statement "Don't repost your questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400273)

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65119284) is a repost of an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65102301) that was closed. The original question was edited to comply with the site policies, and was eventually reopened, but based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65102301/get-serial-date-numbers-from-datenum-in-matlab-from-an-input-cell-array#comment115125426_65102301) by the OP, they simply misunderstood what should happen, and reposted the question. The OP may even have thought they're supposed to include the close banner message in the repost, and did it intentionally.

This happens with reposts of deleted questions as well, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72527518) (see Rev 1), which starts with

> This post is hidden. It was deleted ... by ...

It also happens with reposts of deleted answers, and you'll see the same message as above, for example [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111571), and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73162943). Note that both answers were originally posted on the same questions and were deleted. In the 2nd example, the OP even followed the advice on their original answer, asking them to translate their answer to English.

And sometimes, it's just a careless copy-paste error, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62676947), where it looks like the user copied the question text into the answer and accidentally copied the close banner message as well. (The question was closed a minute after the user posted the answer so this was probably the result of a grace period edit, as there isn't a revision history on the answer).

#### What you should do:

When you see this "banner as text", go ahead and edit it out, since it's definitely not something that should be in a question (or answer).

Reposting content is not allowed on the site, so you could inform the user about this and ask them to edit their original post into shape instead. Questions containing a close banner message is a strong indicator of a repost, so you can look at the user profile to see if you can find the original. If you do, you can flag the new question as a duplicate of the original, and vote to delete it once it's closed. If the user keeps doing this (reposting closed questions), the quality bans will kick in soon enough.

If you notice that there are *multiple* accounts involved, e.g. the repost is from a question posted by a different account, that's an indicator of something more problematic, such as ban evasions, and for that you should raise a moderator flag. See the FAQ [Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368693) which goes over which situations are appropriate for a custom flag.

It's fine to err on the side of caution, and raise a custom flag even if you're not completely sure there's any ban evasion or similar thing going on. After all, it's better to be wrong and it turn out there's nothing problematic going on, rather than not flagging when there is. Also, investigating such issues usually requires being able to search for deleted content, which can be pretty much impossible for regular users, and would need a moderator to investigate. As always, make sure to be as clear and explicit as possible in your custom flag so that moderators know what you mean.

Comment: "due to a misunderstanding of how the close-reopen process works on the site" no, they are doing exactly what the process tells them: "You can edit the question **or post a new one**". It's there on the same text they copied.

Comment: @Braiam It's still a misunderstanding of the process, even if the instructions kind of tell them to do it. You're right that the wording there could be improved. Also, isn't the "post a new one" only for duplicate closures? I don't think other closures include that wording.

Comment: Braiam is correct wrt. "or post a new one" being included in the closure reason as well as being correct that you can _see_ that phrase in the copied text of the [re-posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73146863/15497888) ("You can edit the question or __post a new one.__"). IIRC most (all?) of the network-wide closure reasons include some variant of "[ask a new one](/questions/ask)" (like in the duplicate closure banner) or "[post a new one](/questions/ask)" (like in the needs more focus banner). Our community specific reasons do not include this text.

Comment: I was misremembering about our community specific reasons not suggesting they post a new one. Super user closure includes "[post a new one on Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)", Server Fault includes "[post a new one on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)" and Seeking recommendations includes: "You can edit the question or [post a new one](/help/how-to-ask)" in post owner guidance. So it looks like almost all reasons include posting a new one as an option in their post owner guidance.

Comment: @HenryEcker Oh, I see, that's the text the OP gets presented. Yeah, that phrasing is definitely misleading.

Comment: @Braiam No, it's a misunderstanding of the instruction. The text says to "...or post a new one", not "...or repost the same one". The intent is to instruct them to ask an entirely new and different question. There's been discussion around this phrasing before as it is often misinterpreted by novices.

Comment: @DrewReese why should a user understand "post a new one" when they are told that they will not get answers on this question? If someone told me "post a new one" there's zero percent chances that that's not interpreted as "ask again" by an overwhelming number of users.

Comment: @Braiam So we're in agreement that it seems to be an easily misunderstood instruction. If you ask a poor/bad question and it's closed and you think asking the same question again will result in a different outcome, that's a misunderstanding on your part. In no way does the instruction say to do *exactly* that. Like we've said, this text is easily misunderstandable and there've been discussions to improve it.