# Why was this particular question closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Not what others asked in SO before. It's new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337511/not-what-others-asked-in-so-before-its-new)*

This is my second question. I asked my first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336975/difference-between-r-and-n-in-csv-files?noredirect=1#comment119024677_67336975). But that question was closed quoting that my question is a duplicate of another question.

But I couldn't find my answer to that quoted question. Then again I asked my second question with another name. But it again was closed quoting that my question is a duplicate of some other question. This time the quoted question is completely different from my question.

One user of SO commented on my second question. After a lot of comments between us, I made them understand what my question is. Then they said, "it took me so long to understand this question so as the other community members of SO.". Therefore my question was closed by the community members without even understanding it. How crazy that was!

But I'm very much worried about what SO did.

Comment: A tip: your title should summarize your problem.  Yours is meta-commentary that in no way describes your problem.

Comment: Also, those two questions of yours look really, really similar.  You should edit questions, not repost them.

Comment: Relevant: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/11682469) and [“This question already has answers here” - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/11682469)

Comment: An off-note: "It's urgent for me" - it doesn't matter to us, SO is not customer service. You will get your answer in due time (if somebody finds it interesting enough and/or notices it)

Comment: SO strives to be a repository of programming knowledge, not a free helpdesk. Your question should be clear and be useful to future visitors, so it's perfectly fine to close questions that are unclear. That's also why people ask for clarification in comments which should make you edit your question to clarify it. "But I'm very much worried for what SO did" Keep in mind that we are all volunteers here trying to help you in our free time, you didn't have to pay for the privilege (it's not a right) to ask.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you've been told this yet, so: if a question gets closed, you should *not* repost the exact same question. You should instead edit the closed question to address the feedback you were given, and then it can be re-opened. I'm surprised your second question wasn't closed as a duplicate of your first, in all honesty.

Comment: @F1Krazy the post notice on closed questions [kind of suggest that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/you-can-edit-the-question-or-post-a-new-one) and SE Inc. doesn't seem to be interested in changing that wording in the next 6 to 8 weeks. We can only fight this by insisting and persisting in duplicate closing re-asked questions.

Comment: If [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64417993/3890632) from one of the dupe targets does not answer your question, then I have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Honestly, picking _Not what others asked in SO before. It's new_ as your title is like begging curators to do their utmost best to find an adequate duplicate for your post.

Answer (score 24):

Your question on main boils down to "how come some/many text editors treat both `\r` and `\n` as new line characters when rendering a text file?".

It's not even about CSV files, despite your insistence that it is. Maybe if the question was a bit more to the point and better explained the incorrect dupe wouldn't have been used.

The question is based on a false premise (neither the CSV "format" or python are related to your question; which makes the whole thing confusing), and in the end not particularly interesting.

Maybe a more appropriate dupe could be found if you asked the correct question, but ultimately the answer is: "because it makes sense, what would you expect a text editor to do when encountering these characters?"

If several users have trouble understanding your question, it makes sense to consider that the question is not clear enough, and it might be worth spending some time changing the question. Sometimes adding content, many times *removing* content, so that the question is more focused and easier to grasp.

Try to think about your problem from a different point of view: when having trouble making yourself understood, repeating exactly the same over and over doesn't go well.

Note that despite that, the second time around (after some back and forth in comments), a very accurate dupe was provided as well, with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64417993/3890632) that should fully address your underlying question.

Comment: I don't see why the dupe closure is incorrect. What part of the OP's question isn't covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64417993/3890632)?

Comment: Yeah @khelwood, that's a great answer. But on their [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67336975/1426539) it wasn't present as dupe target. My bad on not spotting it in their second, identical question.

Comment: So the duplicate target can be added.

Comment: @Security Considering the questions are practically identical, deleting one of them would be a better choice IMO. Editing the second one and deleting the first one would be my call, but it's up to the OP.