# Why did this old post suddenly become featured?

Tags: discussion, meta, featured-questions

I've noticed [this old post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/1997232) suddenly acquired a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag. When I open it, there were already my up/down-votes. It seems I've already participated in there, in other words I am done with it.

It would be really good together with adding the tag to also highlight why it was featured. Featuring old topic all of a sudden is at least confusing.

I guess this feature is about to be implemented. Telling us this explicitly would motivate me and other users to participate. Or was it featured because it's about to be closed as "discared"? Or why?

Answer (score 8):

A moderator came across it, that moderator thought it was a good idea and added the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.

It may still not get implemented but the development team has [recently agreed to respond to moderator requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344586/our-commitment-to-responding-to-meta-and-moderators) so I guess this means that moderators are becoming more active in highlighting things they think are good ideas.

Comment: They don't need to feature it, unless they agreed on using [meta-tag:featured] tag as a sign for CMs to see if it merits [meta-tag:status-review]

Comment: @muru: They need to feature it to get enough votes on it to show the CMs that there is community support for that feature.

Comment: Seems to me adding a comment about why a post is featured would be a great idea then, especially when it's an old topic.

Comment: @BDL, is it a guess or a fact? Can you post an answer with "why" answered?

Comment: @Sinatr: 50% guess, 50% practical thinking :). I don't really see the company responding to a 10-votes feature request. Might be different for one with 100th of votes.

Comment: @BDL and this happens to be one with 100+ votes. I don't imagine many of them being from today

Comment: @muru: According to the [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/394048/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries), 78 of the 152 votes (~51%) happened since it has been featured.

Comment: @BDL guess I shouldn't underestimate the sheer traffic driven by SO

Comment: @muru: Yeah, most of the people on SO do not visit meta regularly. The only way to reach them is to feature posts.

Comment: I tend to try and keep up with Meta but I definitely did miss that post. Looking at the dates, it's because I was busy at the time, I might have missed it by just not having enough time to look at everything. So, yes - the featured tag did help me re-discover this.